# qt filedialog directory

Tags: qt, directory, filedialog

i got a QString blabla = qtfiledialog::getOpenFileName();

now blabla gives me the full path and the exe like: C:/Program Files/imanoob.exe

but i only want the path like: C:/Program Files/
how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(path);
const QString path = fileInfo.absolutePath();
```

Comment: Sorry for the "radical" modification. I just made sure that your answer can be copied and pasted while preserving the compilation success.

Comment: @FinalContest You didn't assign the return value of absolutePath()

Comment: Sure, I was just forming the original code as it was. I was thinking about qDebug(), but then I decided to leave it with your personal preference so that I only change it to be compilable. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

`QString getExistingDirectory` to get a directory path.

Or parse the returned string from `getOpenFileName()` by using `QDir` (probably `QDir(blabla).path()` although you need to check the API on the actual method to use).

Comment: That does not seem to be what the OP wanted. getOpenFileName() was already given.