# Copy path to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qfiledialog, qfileinfo

I need to copy the full filepath, without filename, into a QString from QFileDialog below.

```
  QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
      tr("Select app to install"), '/' , tr("APK Files (*.apk)"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [qt filedialog directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097259/qt-filedialog-directory)

Comment: @AndrewMedico: that one is now closed as the duplicate of this. That one might be even deleted based on the downvote numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `QString QFileInfo::absolutePath() const` for this. See the [documentation for details](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#absolutePath).

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
  tr("Select app to install"), '/' , tr("APK Files (*.apk)")));
qDebug() << fileInfo.absolutePath();
```